# how to install PIL for python 3.5 in visual studio 2015

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015

I need to install the PIL module for visual studio 2015

can someone help me please?

I am trying to use the instructions from this site

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I use windowes 10 and i dont know how to open the shell on python

Answer (score 0):

The latest Python builds (3.4 or higher) ship out of the box with the "pip" package manager utility. You should just be able to open a Windows command console and run:

```
pip install Pillow
```

I'm not sure where Visual Studio comes in to this unless you really want to build it yourself (I wouldn't recommend it).